# Is there a way to get the full Cookie data from CookieManager and/or a WebView?

Tags: java, android, cookies

Is there any way to get all of a Cookie's attributes (expires, domain, path, etc) instead of just the value from the CookieManager?

I would like to use the CookieManager and the CookieSyncManager to make it easy to persist cookies across lifecycles and WebViews, but the getCookie() method only returns the NAME=VALUE, and gives no way to modify or read any of the other data about the Cookie.

Also, is there a way to get the Cookies from a WebView?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solutions ?